# How do you hook to an application in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I do not understand how do you hook to an Erlang application since it does not return the `Pid`.

Consider for example the snippet below.I am starting a `Pid` which receives messages to process.However my `application` behaviour does not return anything.
How do i hook to the `Pid` i am interested in when using `application` behaviour ?

**.app**

```
{
  application,simple_app,
  [
    {description,"something"},
    {mod,{simple_app,[]}},
    {modules,[proc]}
  ]
}
```

**app**

```
-module(simple_app).

-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2, stop/1]).

start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    proc:start().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

**module**

```
-module(proc).
-export([start/0]).

start()->
    Pid=spawn_link(?MODULE,loop,[]),
    {ok,Pid}.

loop()->
    receive 
        {From,Message}-> From !  {ok,Message},
                         loop();
        _ ->loop()
    end.
```

**P.S** I am trying to understand how do i get the root `Pid` to further use it to issue commands ? In my case i need the `Pid` of the `proc:start` module.If my root was a supervisor , i would need the `Pid` of the supervisor.The application does not return a `Pid`? How do i hook to it ?
The question thus is when starting the application wouldn't i need a `Pid` returned by it to then be able to issue commands against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application must depend on `kernel` and `stdlib`. You should define their names in your `.app` file, for example:

```erlang
{
  application,simple_app,
  [
    {description,"something"},
    {mod,{simple_app,[]}},
    {modules,[proc]},
    {applications, [kernel, stdlib]}
  ]
}
```

When you want to start your app, you should use the `application` module which is part of the `kernel` application.
It starts some processes to manage your application and I/O handling. It calls `YOUR_APP:start(_, _)` and this function MUST return a Pid which is running the `supervisor` behaviour. We often call it the root supervisor of app.
So you have to define an `application` behaviour (as you did) and a `supervisor` behaviour.
This supervisor process may start your workers which are doing anything your app wants to do.
If you want to start a process, you define its start specification in your supervisor module. So kernel starts your app and your app starts your supervisor and your supervisor starts your worker(s).
You can register your worker pid with a name and you can send it messages by using its name.
If you have lots of workers you can use a pool of pids which maintains your worker pids.

I think it's OK to play with spawn and spawn_link and sending messages manually to processes. But in production code we usually don't do this. We use OTP behaviours and they do this for us in a reliable and clean manner.

I think it's better to write some `gen_server`s (another behaviour) and play with `handle_call` and `handle_cast`, etc callbacks. Then run some `gen_server`s under a supervision tree and play with the supervisor API to kill or terminate its children, etc. Then start writing a complete application.

Remember to read the documentation for behaviours carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and kindness.However my concern was ...how do i get the root `Pid` when starting an application ? In my example the root is indeed a process that gets spawned.But it couldve been a supervisor.The problem is that i want to get a `Pid` as a return when starting the app in order to send it messages (like in my case) or add a child (if my root was a supervisor). The problem is to whom do i issue commands if i do not have a `Pid` returned by my application ?

Comment: The root pid is your supervisor pid. You can register its name  too. start it by using `supervisor:start_link(RegisterName, ...)`.

Comment: Well in the case above do i rlly need to register the root pid in order to use it ? Shouldn't the application behaviour return me something to reference and use ? Its like a started the car but i do not get access to its steering wheel.

Comment: It should not. It is not designed to. It just starts your supervision tree. that's it.

Comment: So if i want to start a child from my top level supervisor , i must register the supervisor , otherwise i cannot grasp it by its `Pid` right , (the application does not return its pid nor it can be querried for its processes)

Comment: Yes. You can register your child too. So you can send messages to it directly by its name.

Comment: Ok i see , so in a dynamic world , lets say an app that is distributed across multiple nodes , in order to name each of your top level supervisors ,how do you ensure uniquness between your atoms ?

Comment: In distributed world we use custom registries like `gproc`, etc.